# Problems with initialize Tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I set the editor on the frontend and have a problem, how to initialize `tinymce` in this case.

My code:

```
<head>
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <a class=pageedit>Редактировать</a>
<div id="textwidget" class="textwidget">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati esse enim facilis quam magnam nihil excepturi ipsa, maxime ducimus sapiente, repudiandae facere mollitia, velit quia dolore doloribus molestiae odit fuga?
</div>
</body>

 /*JQUERY*/
  $(document).ready(function() {

      $('a.pageedit').on('click', function() {

          $('#textwidget').wrap('<form class="tinymce"><textarea class="tiny" name="page"></textarea></form>');

          $(this).unbind('click');
          setTimeout(function() {
             Tinit();
          },100);
      });

  });

function Tinit() {
      tinymce.init({ 
        selector:'textarea.tiny',
        height: 600,
        plugins: [
          'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
          'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
          'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code'
        ],
        toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
      });

      $('form.tinymce').submit(function() {
         return false;
      });

      $('form.tinymce').on('submit', function() {
        var page = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url: 'publish.php',
          data: page,
          success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            document.location.href = '';
          },
          error: function() {
            alert('error');
          }
        });
      });

}
```

In the end, the editor is loaded, but empty inside. How can I solve it?

Is reproduced here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZEEwG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can easily be done. Just make sure the tinymce source element contains the desired content before initializing tinymce.
The other option is to set the tinymce content after initialization.

```
  tinymce.init({ 
    selector:'textarea.tiny',
    height: 600,
    plugins: [
      'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
      'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
      'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code'
    ],
    toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
    setup : function(ed)
    {

      ed.on('init', function(evt)
      {
        ed.setContent($('#textwidget').html());
      });
    }
  });

 ....
}
```

**Update**: On submit do:

```
$('form.tinymce').on('submit', function() {
    //  Calls the save method on all editor instances in the collection. This can be useful when a form is to be submitted.
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();

    ....
});
```

Comment: Now the html code in the editor, but when sending the form to the server in the textarea is empty

Comment: before sending the form execute ed.triggerSave();   this will update the tinymce source element with the editor content